# Save an array to device

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, save

I am trying to save certain data on the device that is running my app. The code for saving the data looks like this:

```
Future<File> writeContent() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file. ...;
  }

Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/UserData.txt');
  }
```

My problem is that I don't simply want to save a String I want to **save a list (array)** to the Phone. Is there a way to do so? 
There has to come something where you see the `...`.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert (`pref_dessert`) to achieve this..you can create a custom class with what are all the details you want to store..and everytime you want to store something..create an object for it same that object.. similarly.. whenever you need the stored details...you can get the object and read details from it

Comment: You could simply encode your array to a JSON String, save that string, and when you retrieve it, decode it back to an array. You can see an example of doing this with SharedPreferences here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPrpk_JiGvc

Answer (score 0):

You should use local database like SQLite to handle this problem, you can use this package [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pref_dessert](https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert) package to achieve this..

You can create a custom class with what are all the details you want to store..

And everytime you want to store something..create an object for it same that object..

Similarly.. whenever you need the stored details...you can get the object and read details from it.

You can get to know more from an example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert#-example-tab-).